# Smarter viewing of program output in terminal - show/hide buttons for lower priority outputs, allowing drilldown of program output

Tags: c++, python, xterm

Many of my programs output run-time information to the terminal, things like:

```
running minimisation  

    ----rep 10.  val=2.30498  
    ----rep 20.  val=1.98377  
    ----...  
    ----...  
    ----...  
    ----rep 90. vsl=1.77921  

minimisation finished. val=1.76221.  93 reps.
```

Are there ways of hiding some of this information (e.g. the indented part) BUT be able to expand/hide it by using +/- buttons?

(In most cases I am using python or c++, called from e.g. xterm on linux)

I've not found any things like this, so pointers to related solutions would also be helpful.

Comment: No, a terminal does not support buttons.  You either need to code up some GUI yourself, or generate output suitable for e.g. Emacs outline mode or org mode.

Comment: Thanks Sven, emacs outline looks close to what I want (also good to know that I'm not going to get it just from a terminal - I can stop looking :).  I presumed that this would be something that many people wanted in the case of eg looking at logfiles etc - if people have other suggestions, I'd be interested to know about them before I go for outline.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this information as a log of your programm's work, you could output it into a file, and format the file as XML or something like that, which will allow you to easily view the file and do whatever you want.

If you need it for debugging, consider using some IDE with a debugging GUI.

Comment: It's mainly for seeing what the program is doing _while_ it is running.  I want to output a lot of information, in case some of it is useful/interesting to me (eg 'oh no, we are stuck in slow minimisation' or 'hey, that function found a good solution'), BUT I want to hide the more detailed information and only have it visible by drilling down.